# Group by sum totals

Tags: sql, teradata

Been trying to pull together a view of our customers where you sum the total of a column, then count the number of customers that fall into that sum.

Might be easier to show in table form. My table is set up simply as below

```
customer  registration state
---------------------------
  a            100
  a            50
  b            100
  c            50
  d            100
  d            100
  e            100
  e            50
```

How would I change this to;

```
reg state     customer count
----------------------------
  200            1
  150            2
  100            1
  50             1
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this in two steps. First find the total registration state for each customer. Then count the customers that have same total.

```
select reg_state,
       count(customer)
  from (
        select customer,
               sum(registration_state) as reg_state
          from your_table
         group by customer
       ) x
 group by reg_state;
```